# How the function NDSolve works?

Tags: differential-equations, system

I am trying to numerically solve a system of ordinary differential equations.

```
beta = 1.59*10^-8;
delta = 10^-6;
p = 23.91;
c = 10^-8;

system1 = {
u'[t] == -beta*u[t]*v[t],
i'[t] == beta*u[t]*v[t] - delta*i[t],
v'[t] == p*i[t] - c*v[t]
};

initials = {
u[0] == 70000, i[0] == 0, v[0] == 20000};

nds = NDSolve[{system1, initials}, {u[t], i[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, 10000}];
Plot[{u[t]} /. nds, {t, 0, 10000}]
```

Next, I'm building a solution for u(t)/
So, when I get the solution of the system for 0<=t<=100. I have this function:
[image]
But when I get the solution of the system for 0<=t<=10 000. I have this function:
[image]
And you can see that these two constructed functions are very different: the values of the first function are non-negative, but the values of the second one fall below zero. What is the reason for this?

Comment: I noticed that such fluctuations begin when 0<=t<=525

Comment: The magnitude of oscillations allowed around $u=0$ are controlled by the option `AccuracyGoal` (default ~8, i.e. oscillations kept below around $10^{-8}$).  Use `AccuracyGoal -> 100` etc. to control the magnitude of the oscillations, if desired, down to the limitations of machine precision. If you wish to keep $u > 0$, make the substitution $w = \log u$ in `system1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look on the different axes scales of your two plots!

Try `PlotRange->All`

```
Plot[{u[t]} /. nds, {t, 0, 10000}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! I'm so new to this.

Comment: Recommend that you use `LogLogPlot`